# Random UI freeze on ArchLinux

Tags: arch-linux, freeze

### Hardware

Lenovo ThinkPad L14 Gen1 (Intel, ref 20U1000XFR) (see [AL wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Laptop/Lenovo#L_series))

### Software versions

```
Operating System: Arch Linux
KDE Plasma Version: 5.20.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.78.0
Qt Version: 5.15.2
Kernel Version: 5.10.7-arch1-1
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz
Memory: 16 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics
Compositor: OpenGL: 3.1 (switched back to 2.0)
```

### Issue

I'm booting without issue, logging in SDDM into my KDE session, can use the desktop, etc.
Randomly, sometimes after 5 minutes, sometimes after 30 minutes, sometimes after an hour it crashes and sometimes I don't experience any crash in 2 days, sometimes it crashes 4 times a day.
It's not really a crash but a screen freeze, the whole UI stops responding, but all the process underneath are still running. I can't switch to a TTY with `ALT` + `F2`, the only solution is a hard reboot. It start happening about 2 weeks ago.

After each freeze and reboot, I observed the logs with `journalctl -xe -b -1` but never saw any error. I didn't see something noticeable in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` either. Since I'm clueless for the reason I can't find an explanation why it's happening. Is it a driver, the kernel, plasma, xorg, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

I also have the L14 and have experienced similar freezes or my keyboard locking on a single keypress and then resorting to a hard reset. Based on the discussions and suggestions of

- https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/kqfjxu/arch_linux_randomly_freezes/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/kqadu8/arch_is_freezing_randomly/

I swopped to the LTS kernel and this has stopped the freezing 99% of the time.

Comment: Yay I switched to LTS an no problem anymore, but I'd like to know what to fix with vanilla kernel.